# how to change fix slider to responsive slider in height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

i'm using the wordpress Colr theme, I have a simple page with a slider inside. The goal here is to have a responsive slider when the page is resized. 
I tried to play with the img balise but can't fixed my problem

HTML part of the slider:

```
<div class="images">
    <div class="wp-caption" style="width: auto; display: block;">
        <img src="http://.../wp-content/uploads/2019/02/1.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-24" style="height: 564px;">
    </div>
<div class="images">
    <div class="wp-caption" style="width: auto; display: block;">
        <img src="http://.../wp-content/uploads/2019/02/2.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-24" style="height: 564px;">
    </div>    

<div class="images">
    <div class="wp-caption" style="width: auto; display: block;">
        <img src="http://.../wp-content/uploads/2019/02/3.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-24" style="height: 564px;">
    </div>
```

this theme is not so responsive, i mean when i resize the page the slide stay at the same height and width and i can't have something responsive. May be a css part is needed here with the class ?

With jwmoreland code:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

we have this result
[image: slider with scrollbar]
instead of this one
[image: slider with border and no scrollbar]

Answer (score 0):

Adding a max-width to the image helps. I think the javascript though is adding a height property which messes with its aspect ratio. I had to override that with an !imporant statement.

```
img {
   width: 600px;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
}
```

**Update** - It seems that my above solution might make the image extend bigger than desired on wide screens. To limit it, add a width, then it will stay that width until it hits the edge of it's bounding box (that resizes with the screen).

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please take a look to the result, the height is bigger than the page with your soluce. something with this result is what i'm trying to do: https://micheleyong.com

Comment: I edited the answer above to limit the width of the image (I put 600px, but you can change that to fit your desired width).

Comment: yep seen that thank you, but how can i do if all images must have same height and not same width ?  because when i try to resize the page vertically, nothing changes, you can test my page, i update it with your code. May be here we need to let px height and width to images and try to play with 100% height and width to parent div ? what do you think, but i can't achieve that

Answer (score 0):

using img balise was the solution, the goal here xas to remove the img attribut by default like that:

```
 img {
  width: auto!important;
  height: auto!important;
  max-height: 70%!important;
  max-width: 70%!important;
  position: absolute!important;
  top: 0!important;
  bottom: 0!important;
  left: 0!important;
  right: 0!important;
  margin: auto!important;
}
```